# How to instal phpDocumntor on Symfony4?

Tags: php, symfony, phpdoc

I'm trying to install phpDocumentor on my project, but I've got this problem.

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[v3.1.0, ..., v3.1.2] require symfony/cache ^5.0 -> found symfony/cache[v5.0.0, ..., v5.3.7] but the package is fixed to v4.4.30 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.
    - Root composer.json requires phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor ^3.1 -> satisfiable by phpdocumentor/phpdocumentor[v3.1.0, v3.1.1, v3.1.2].

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
```

I really don't want to change my Symfony version and I haven't found the way to install the phpDoc on that project :c Do you have any ideas how to install it without changing my project version?

Answer (score 1):

Taking a quick look at the phpDocumentor history, I don't think there's a version that'll be compatible with Symfony 4; they go from [Symfony 2 on v2.9](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/blob/v2.9.1/composer.json) to [Symfony 5 on v3.0](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/phpDocumentor/blob/v3.0.0/composer.json).

I'm not sure you'd want to tie up your project's requirements with those of an external tool like that, anyway.

I'd suggest using the [phar distribution](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/getting-started/installing.html#by-downloading-the-phar).  If you want it included with your project when it's cloned, you can either commit it to the repo or download it with a [Composer script](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md) on install.